# Pasando datos de Diccionario Python Django a Consulta SQL

Tags: sql, python-3.x, django

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
        params = {
        'val':  '\'%' + val + '%\'',
        'access_map_id': access_map_id,
        }
    sql = \
        '''
        SELECT id, first_name, last_name,
               username, email, position, user_image
        FROM users
        WHERE (
            first_name ILIKE %(val)s OR
            last_name ILIKE %(val)s OR
            last_name ILIKE %(val)s OR
            username ILIKE %(val)s OR
            email ILIKE %(val)s
        )
        AND id NOT IN (
            SELECT user_id_id AS id
            FROM  menu_access
            WHERE access_map_id_id = %(access_map_id)s
        )
        ORDER BY first_name

        ''' % params
    users = User.objects.raw(sql)
    print(users)
```

Necesito usar el mismo valor val del diccionario tantas veces lo necesite para buscar al usuario en la base de datos, pero recibo el siguiente error:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Y esto es obvio porque tengo sólo 2 valores en el diccionario "params", pero en el where le estoy accediendo 5 veces a un mismo valor.

Como puedo pasarle el mismo valor de diccionario a la consulta?

podría hacer  `% (val, val, val, val, val, access_map_id)` pero para qué repetir la misma variable??

Espero haberme dado a entender

Answer (score 2):

La sustitución de los valores de la query `sql`que tu propones no es sintácticamente válida.
Échale un ojo a la [documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/sql/#passing-parameters-into-raw), te llevará al siguiente código:

```
params = {
    'val': '\'%' + val + '%\'',
    'access_map_id': access_map_id,
}
sql = '''
    SELECT id, first_name, last_name,
           username, email, position, user_image
    FROM users
    WHERE (
        first_name ILIKE %(val)s OR
        last_name ILIKE %(val)s OR
        last_name ILIKE %(val)s OR
        username ILIKE %(val)s OR
        email ILIKE %(val)s
    )
    AND id NOT IN (
        SELECT user_id_id AS id
        FROM  menu_access
        WHERE access_map_id_id = %(access_map_id)s
    )
    ORDER BY first_name
'''
users = User.objects.raw(sql, params)
print(users)
```

Ojo con las restricciones, ese método propuesto como solución, no funciona con SQLite.